# Haskell Persistent Postgres - How to set default schema?

Tags: haskell, persistent

I can't access to schemas except `public`.

1. How to define schema of persistent entity?
2. How to set table name different from its type name?
3. Is there any way to make my entity's primary key other than Int64? maybe String.